# How can I check whether properties passed to my Angular directives are expressions or literals?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm upgrading a legacy application, converting lots of repetitive code into Angular 1.5 "Components".

One repeating pattern is the use of a button with an `ng-click` which performs a task on a related model, for which I've created a component.

However the legacy use of these buttons come in two forms. One where the ng-click is a function reference to something defined in the parent scope, sometimes passed several components down e.g:

```
<button ng-click="someScope.deleteFunc">delete</button>
```

...another where the ng-click is an "inline" function (My terminology may be a little off). e.g:

```
<button ng-click="alert('hello world')">delete</button>
```

I would like my component to support both formats, since refactoring every use of these buttons isn't feasible e.g :

```
<special-button click-action="someScope.deleteFunc">Whatever</special-button>
// or
<special-button click-action="alert('hello world')">Whatever</special-button>
```

What I can't work out, is how to support these in my button controller. If I try to call `$scope.clickAction()()` it works in the first instance, but throws errors in the second (having successfully run the function, but that's not the point - I want no errors).

Is there some way of parsing whether `clickAction` is a reference or a literal? (I've investigated `$parse`, but can't see a solution) Or am I going this all the wrong way? Or have I no option but to require the click function to be passed the same way universally?

I had thought that I could do:

```
if(scope.clickAction && typeof scope.clickAction() === "function") {
    // etc
}
```

... but of course this immediately executes `clickAction()` in the cases where it's an expression.

**UPDATE:**
Here is my component code:

```
(function (){
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myapp')
    .component('specialButton', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/shared/specialButton/specialButton.html',
        replace: true,
        controller: specialButtonCtrl,
        controllerAs: 'specialbutton',
        bindings: {
            clickAction: '&',
        },
    });

function specialButtonCtrl() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.click = function () {
         vm.clickAction();
    };
}
})(angular);
```

Comment: Can you share your directive declaration with us? I think ur supposed to be able to do this using the '&' identified in the scope attributes.

Comment: Done, thanks in advance ^^

Comment: I suppose the obvious solution is just to add parentheses to the function references versions wherever they are e.g `<special-button click-action="someScope.deleteFunc">Whatever</special-button>`
becomes `<special-button click-action="someScope.deleteFunc()">Whatever</special-button>`

Answer (score 1):

I might have misunderstood you, but looks like you simply need to make use of the & binding. I created this jsfiddle to exemplify. Hope it helps! :)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('specialButton',
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div class="button" ng-click="clickAction()">Call home!</div>',
      controllerAs: 'specialbutton',
      scope: {
        clickAction: '&'
      }
    };
  }
);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.callHome = function(message) {
    alert(message);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0/angular-1.0.0.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">

    <special-button click-action="callHome('called home!')">
    </special-button>

  </div>
</div>
```